# Output days of week on calendar month-view, with first column being Saturday, in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I have the following C# code which should output all the days in a given month of a given year. The calendar columns should start on a Saturday:

```
int year = 2023;
int month = 5;

DateTime firstDayOfMonth = new DateTime(year, month, 1);
int daysInMonth = DateTime.DaysInMonth(year, month);

DayOfWeek firstDayOfWeek = firstDayOfMonth.DayOfWeek;
int offset = (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday - (int)firstDayOfWeek;
    
if (offset < 0) offset += 7;

Console.WriteLine(firstDayOfMonth.ToString("MMMM yyyy"));
Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(" Sa Su Mo Tu We Th Fr");

for (int i = 0; i < offset; i++) {
    Console.Write("   ");
}

for (int day = 1; day <= daysInMonth; day++) {
    Console.Write($"{day,3}");
    if ((offset + day) % 7 == 0) {
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
}

if ((offset + daysInMonth) % 7 != 0) {
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

There's a [Fiddle here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/0adugk).

Whilst this works for April (where month is set to 4) it's not working correctly for May — it's showing the 1st May as being a Thursday when in fact it should be a Monday. I'm fairly sure it's because of an issue with how the offset is being calculated but I'm struggling to figure out how to resolve it as my C# isn't great.

Could anyone suggest how to get this working robustly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The days of the week are numbered from Sunday to Saturday, with Sunday being 0. That means that you could consider any day of the week's number to be its offset into the week from Sunday, without any further calculation. In order to adjust for Saturday being the first day, you need to add one to the first day of the month’s day number, wrapping Saturday (which would become day 7) around to 0. You could do that like this:

```
int offset = ((int)firstDayOfWeek + 1) % 7;
// int offset = (int)DayOfWeek.Saturday - (int)firstDayOfWeek;

// if (offset < 0) offset += 7;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you substract the index for the offset taking the INT value of the day, so Saturday has a value of 6, whereas in your case it should be 0. You should rewrite day indexes based on your days order:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int, int> { { 0, 1 }, { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3}, { 3, 4 }, { 4, 5 }, { 5, 6 }, { 6, 0 } }; // New days order. Key: normal day order, value - your day order
int offset = dict[(int)firstDayOfWeek];
```